# Dynamic (background) image on every page of BIRT report

Tags: java, pdf-generation, birt

I want to write dynamic text vertically on the right side of every page within a pdf document generated with Birt (2.5.2)

This leads me into two problems that maybe can be solved independently:

1. Write text vertically
2. Put this on every page on the right side (header and footer cannot help me there)

**For problem 1)**

I could not find a way to write text vertically, so I decided to put my text into a JLabel, do a 90 degree rotation, write the image into a ByteArrayOutputStream and use the byteArray to add a dynamic image into my report.
=> This is already working, if there is an easy 3 line solution I hadn't think of, I will listen to reason :)

**For problem 2)**

Due to the fact, the header and footer are not useable for an image / text on the right or left my approach was to use a background image and put it to the right.

**The problem is, a background image in birt can be only an URL or an embedded image** 
To use my generated byteArray I need to use a dynamic image.

So right now I can only think of one possible solution: Save my generated image into a temp folder with a unique url, add this image as background image and delete it afterwards.
But I think there should be an easier solution.

**==> UPDATE 1**

I created a two column layout to add my dynamic image on the right side. My report has a maximum of five pages, so I put the images five times in it with a page break before each image. This is working and the result is as expected... with a new problem left:

In some conditions, the report has 3 or 4 pages, so I need to hide the last images. I can get the number of pages at the end of the report within the first column with "reportContext.getPageVariable('pageNumber')" and save it to my own report variable. Each of the five images get a number 1 to 5 and a hide condition if the number is bigger than my last page number.

Now I need the right place where I get my pageNumber:

- On render of the last element in the first column gets the right number, but it is set later than I use it in the second column
- On render of the row returns always 1 but it is set before using it in the second column
- Adding a second row will return the right page number but is set later than I use it in the second column

Does anybody know how to do this?

http://eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportScripting.php

**==> UPDATE 1 END**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its done and now, as I know how it works... it's easy ;)

For everyone else have the same problem, here is how you get the same content on every page as a sidebar:

1. Create a two column grid for the whole page and add your content in one column.
2. Within the data explorer create a report variable `maxPages` with default value `0`
3. Add a text element as last element in the content column with following properties

   - Hide element, expression: true
   - "On render" script:

     ```
     vars["maxPages"] = reportContext.getPageVariable("pageNumber");
     ```
4. Add your recurring element in the second column with following properties

   - Page Break - Before: Always (except the first element)
   - Hide element, expression:

     ```
     vars["maxPages"] != 0 && vars["maxPages"] <= reportContext.getPageVariable("pageNumber")
     ```

     - *NOTE 1*: compare `maxPages` with 0 to show the first pages, the variable is available the first time on the page it is set in the first column
     - *NOTE 2*: compare with smaller then because of the page break before, the variable `pageNumber` contains one less than the real page number!

In my case, the recurring item is a dynamic image with the vertical text, but this could be everything, just wrap each occurrence within a grid

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative approach:

1. Set up your report with a 2-column, 1-row grid. Stretch the grid to be the length of the paper.
2. Set up a dummy dataset that has numeric columns defined, but always returns no records (for example, by including a `where 1=0` condition).
3. Add a graph on the dummy dataset to the right hand cell of the grid. Set everything apart from the y-axis title to be non-visible or transparent.
4. Enter the desired text into the y-axis title, and set the text direction, font size, etc. as desired in the y-axis title's font dialog.
5. Adjust the main grid's cell widths so that the right hand cell is aligned with the right hand side of the page and is just wide enough to display the desired text.
6. Insert the rest of the report into the left hand cell of the main grid.

The problem with this approach (apart from it being a bit complicated) is that the y-axis title can't easily be set to dynamic text, as far as I know. Possible approaches to setting it might either be to change it in an event script within the report, or alternatively to give it a lookup key (in the graph y-axis title Externalize Text dialog) and set the lookup value dynamically when running the report.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry for my late response, I had to work on other issues first and tried two other solution I was thinking of.
GraphicMasterPages seemed to be just for this purpose... but have not been implemented, yet.

Comment: The second approach was to add a background and replace the image after loading it to the memory by birt scripts.

Comment: Your idea was at least a bit helpful, I created a two column layout and put my generated image in the right column 5 times with a page break before each image. This is working fine for the full report with 5 pages. But in some conditions the report can have 3 or 4 pages. I will add a new response for this problem.